# Efficiently perform a signed square root on a L1 normalized OpenCV descriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have matrix where each row is a SURF descriptor in 64 dimensions. For each row, I need to:

1. L1 normalize it
2. For each element, compute its signed square root

The only way that I came out with this is:

```
template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

void SURFOpenCV::ComputeDescriptors(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat1f &descriptors){
    descriptors.release();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> pts;
    surf->detectAndCompute(img, cv::Mat(), pts, descriptors);
    //if there is at least one keypoint
    if(pts.size()){
        // For each row
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows; ++i) {
            // Perform L1 normalization on the whole descriptor
            cv::normalize(descriptors.row(i), descriptors.row(i), 1.0, 0.0, cv::NORM_L1);
            for (int j = 0; j<descriptors.cols; j++) {
                float val = descriptors.at<float>(i,j);
                descriptors.at<float>(i,j) = sgn(val) * std::sqrt(val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But since **performance are crucial**, this looks kinda inefficient to me. Any better (faster) solution?

Comment: What part of your algorithm does your profiler indicate consumes the most time?

Comment: I didn't profile it, but it's good practice to avoid to operate on single elements and prefer specific functions which operates on the whole vector/array/data structure, don't you think?

Comment: Did you miss a `abs`? `std::sqrt(std::abs(val))` ?

Comment: @Miki oh gosh I did :D However, operating element looks so inefficient to me.

Comment: I made a couple of tests yesterday.. both were something like 2x faster then your approach, but the speed up make sense only for something like 10000 rows. I think that your descriptors are much less, so in practice there's no difference. Are you still interested in those?

Comment: Surf are 64 floats, right? Or 128? I forgot ;)

Comment: 64! No, because it would mean 10k descriptors per image, which are **really** too many! However describing 5k images takes around 120s and 4s for this normalization (called RootSURF). I guess that we can achieve some improvement by parallelize it.

Comment: I agree, that's why I haven't posted an answer. Can't you parallelize on image basis?